# WinRe.wim is in wrong place

Tags: windows-11, recovery

Windows 11

I had trouble enabling the Windows recovery environment and it turned out that the `WinRe.wim` file was not in the default location of

```
C:\Windows\System32\Recovery
```

but was rather in

```
C:\Windows\SysWOW64\Recovery
```

I ran the command

```
reagentc /setreimage /path C:\Windows\SysWOW64\Recovery
```

after which I was able to enable Windows recovery environment.
But why is WinRe.wim in the wrong place, and what can I do about it?
I tried manually copying it into `C:\Windows\System32\Recovery`, but Windows deletes it from there.

Comment: Not to worry -- the Windows Recovery Environment, in itself, is incomplete; it does not contain many of the tools needed for repair. Furthermore, if it's on the main drive, and there is an *issue with that drive*, it's useless. Better to create a Win RE (or PE) on USB with those tools, such as pre-built Hiren's Boot CD PE. https://www.hirensbootcd.org/, Ultimate Boot CD, https://www.ultimatebootcd.com/, or alternatives: https://alternativeto.net/software/hiren39s-bootcd/. Better yet, use a disk imaging tool  to make an image of the drive, and a rescue USB with WinRE or PE to recover the image.

Comment: I have Macrium Reflect backups, and a USB recovery media. But the WRE can be useful sometimes